# Not found curl: null. Apache Tomcat Deployment Azure DevOps

Tags: curl, tomcat, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Let me explain what I am doing, I am using this task. The problem comes when the agent tries to deploy my .war in my Tomcat. My Tomcat is a docker container that I have already configured the manager, I have set the roles etc. It is running in my localhost:8080. So, the logs says this "Not found curl: null". I checked the capabilities of my agent and it has this capability also in the path.
I have already attached an image but I will add the path here

[curl capability path in my agent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gxK73.png)

path:C:_tools\jdk-17.0.5.8-hotspot\bin;C:\Python39\Scripts;C:\Python39;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA NvDLISR;C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\bin;C:\ProgramData\DockerDesktop\version-bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs;C:\maven\apache-maven-3.8.6\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin\curl.exe;C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\NetworkService\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps

capability curl.

The issue reported is this "Not found curl: null" in my pipeline

[Issue from my log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jJzBQ.png)
Please I am desperate, I don't know if I am doing something wrong. Please I need help

Thank you so much!

I tried several times deleting and creating the agent changing the location of curl. But I didn't get any solution. As I said I would like if someone could help me with this because I don't find any solution .

Comment: Hi and welcome, try [to post text not as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557)

Comment: I tested in my pipeline with the task `Deploy to Apache Tomcat` by following this steps[Deploy to Apache Tomcat Server](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tomcat/blob/master/src/tomcat.md) and it worked fine. Have a try to check your septs and set the `debug=true` to get full error information.

Answer (score 0):

I tested the task `Deploy to Apache Tomcat` used to  deploy a web application in my pipeline  by following this doc:[tomcat.md](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tomcat/blob/master/src/tomcat.md) and it worked fine.

My environment:

Windows 10,CURL 7.8,JDK 1.8,Tomcat9.0

1 if you don’t install Curl on build agent and make sure cURL is reported as an agent capability, the pipeline builds fail with this error information：
[image: No agent found which statisfies demands:curl]

**But from your issue log, it’s obviously you’ve installed Curl and configured well.**

2 after adding curl into agent capability, the build pipeline runs successfully.
[image: install curl in agent]

Here’s my task information:

```
task.TomcatDeployment@1
  displayName: 'Deploy application to a Tomcat server'
  inputs:
    TomcatUrl: 'http://localhost:8080/'
    Username: ''
    Password: ''
    Warfile: DemoWebsite.war
    Context: /webdemo
```

Result

[image: RESULT]

3 I find it is curl in this path  **`C:\Windows\system32\curl.exe`** that actually executes the deployment command.
 `C:\Windows\system32\curl.exe` is included by default on windows 10 .

Maybe you can check your path  `C:\Windows\system32` and make sure if curl exists.

I'm not sure if that will fully address your problem, though.